# How can i use a symbol from a value of a radiobutton to calculate with two numbers?

Tags: javascript

```
    main.onclick = function(evt){
      calculate(evt.target.value)
    };

    function calculate(ex){

        let calc = (Number(inp1.value)) + `${ex}` + (Number(inp2.value))
        console.log(calc)

    }
```

I am trying to make a calculator where i use radiobuttons to define what to do. The value of evt(the radiobuttons) is either +, -, * , /. I want to use evt.value to calculate two numbers from the two inputvalues using one of those four symbols. If i the value of evt is for instance "*", i want calc to be (2(inp1.value) * 3(inp2.value) = 6, but this doesent work with the example i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` function to calculate the value of `calc`

```
eval(calc)
```